# How to make assert_select in a integration test select a css class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing, minitest

I'm building my integrations tests, and i need to assure that a HTML tag has an specific integer as value, but i get this error:

```
ReportsTest
  test_report_shows_the_right_data_for_last_30_days              ERROR (0.94s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass
            test/integration/reports_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:ReportsTest>'
            test/test_helper.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
            test/test_helper.rb:45:in `block in test'
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="panel panel-default report-summary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Resumen</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 summary-item">
        <div class="summary-value resources-count"><%= @resources_count %></div>
        <div class="summary-label">Recursos Publicados</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 summary-item">
        <div class="summary-value"><%= @likes_count %></div>
        <div class="summary-label">Likes</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 summary-item">
        <div class="summary-value"><%= @searches_count %></div>
        <div class="summary-label">Búsquedas</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 summary-item">
        <div class="summary-value"><%= @comments_count %></div>
        <div class="summary-label">Comentarios</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 summary-item">
        <div class="summary-value"><%= @views_count %></div>
        <div class="summary-label">Vistas</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 summary-item">
        <div class="summary-value"><%= @users.count %></div>
        <div class="summary-label">Colaboradores</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ReportsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'show report without time range', subdomain: :mainco do
    sign_in users(:juan)
    visit reports_path
    assert_equal 2, page.all(".report-resources table tbody tr").count
  end

  test 'report shows the right data for last 30 days', subdomain: :mainco do
    sign_in users(:juan)
    visit reports_path
    knowledge_bases(:sales).resources.create!(user: users(:juan), 
        title: "JavaScript", type: "Discussion", created_at: 31.days.ago)

    assert_select ".resources-count" do |elements|
      elements.each do |element|
        assert_equal element, 1
      end
    end
  end

end
```

It seems like my assert_select is not correctly finding the HTML tag with the css class resources-count.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using capybara and need to check the content of an element you can do something like:

```
assert page.has_css?('.resources-count', text: "something")
```

`assert_select` is not going to work here because you are creating an integration test, not a controller test.

---

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
assert_select '.resources-count', "1"
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views

Comment: This is kinda confusing. I have `class OrdersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` in `test/controllers` and `assert_select` looks for `<select>` tag. This is because it cames from `Capybara` not from Rails(?).   So if your test responds to `page => #<Capybara::Session>`, than You need to use @germanescobar resonse.